# Techniques for drawing lines, with mouse, on 3D objects in WebGL or OpenGL?

Tags: opengl-es2, webgl

Can anyone point me to techniques for drawing lines, with the mouse, on 3D objects in WebGL or OpenGL?

Here's the effect I'm looking for, using WebGL: http://www.spacegoo.com/cadillac/

I can imagine the general idea - projecting a ray onto the surface, then perhaps using normals and UVs, transform the intersections into UV-space and drawing the line on a texture, which gets mapped onto the object.

Would love to find some proper literature on it though.

Answer (score 1):

You could start by taking a look at the JavaScript code of that page you've linked to figure out how they did it. I'd guess each line is composed by a lot of tiny rounded dots used as decals. That could explain why the lines look dotted when seen from close. I don't think using decals would be the most efficient technique, but it should be the simplest to implement.

Here are some refs from google, if you want to take a look:

- SO: [How can I speed up painting on a texture in OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26220887/how-can-i-speed-up-painting-on-a-texture-in-opengl-3-3-4-1) - Likely what you wanna do.
- ["Texture Bombing"](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch20.html) technique for lots of decals.
- [How to project decals](http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/06/how-to-project-decals/) blog post.

Apart from that, [Virtual Texturing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MegaTexture) techniques can greatly simplify and improve texture painting, but just getting a VT system to work properly is a tremendous amount of work, so I doubt that would be relevant to you...

Comment: Thanks, yes I figure it's about a ray-pick to find the UVs at the intersection, then using those to find the pixels to update on the texture image.

BTW I've looked at that page and since it has minified JavaScript, it's not much use as an example.